# ERROR at line 13: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following SQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE staff(
SID NUMBER(20) PRIMARY KEY,
STAFF_NAME VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
DESIGNATION VARCHAR2(30) DEFAULT 'ASSISTANT PROFESSOR',
GENDER CHAR NOT NULL,
DOB DATE,
DOJ DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE,
SALARY NUMBER(7,2),
MOBILE NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
EMAIL VARCHAR2(20),
PRESENT_ADDRESS VARCHAR2(70),
EXPERIENCE NUMBER(1,1),
DEPT_ID VARCHAR2(2) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES DEPT(DEPT_ID)
)
/
```

But I get this output:

> DEPT_ID VARCHAR2(2) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES DEPT(DEPT_ID)
>                       *
>    ERROR at line 13:
>   ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

What is causing the problem?

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it not:

```
CREATE TABLE staff (
    SID NUMBER(20) PRIMARY KEY
    ,STAFF_NAME VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL
    ,DESIGNATION VARCHAR2(30) DEFAULT 'ASSISTANT PROFESSOR'
    ,GENDER CHAR NOT NULL
    ,DOB DATE
    ,DOJ DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE
    ,SALARY NUMBER(7, 2)
    ,MOBILE NUMBER(10) NOT NULL
    ,EMAIL VARCHAR2(20)
    ,PRESENT_ADDRESS VARCHAR2(70)
    ,EXPERIENCE NUMBER(1, 1)
    ,DEPT_ID VARCHAR2(2)
    ,FOREIGN KEY (DEPT_ID) REFERENCES DEPT(DEPT_ID)
    )
```

See between [FOREIGN KEY] and [REFERENCES]

Comment: 100%.  Posted both, due to not having Oracle installed - so I could not check the syntax - used Notepad++ .  One of the top programmers' friend.  Don't forget to mark accepted.

Comment: Thanks @miracle173.   Updated.